# how to simulate timeout on Ie 8?

Tags: php

one of my user has time out issue on my website - where in my php script takes more than 30 seconds to execute, her IE times out and shows an IE error message.

But it never does to me - my IE will continously just wait even if i let my PHP script to sleep for 6 minutes.

Is there any way to set the timeout or force my IE to timeout for say in 5 seconds?

Comment: As to a root cause... this may be due to using a proxy server that is set to auto-timeout after 30seconds.  Therefore nothing that you can control - however I'd argue that if a page takes longer than 30 seconds to return - **that** is the problem, not the timeout.  In your PHP are you `flush()`ing your results to the browser at all? or waiting until you have the entire page content?

Comment: hi guys thanks for trying to help - the problem is i am requesting flight information from expedia, a response that i have no control on how long it will take. I can fix this, by probably sending responses to the browser every now and then while waiting a response. BUT in order for me to do that, I need something to test on, so i need to simualte an time out on my IE, but my IE never times out that is the problem.

Comment: just checking... are you using AJAX to get data from Expedia? or using iframes? or is this being done server side?

Comment: this is done using server side - Zend_Http_Client. Then wham, after very many seconds IE shows that.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this depends on the browser. But here a link http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php

Comment: hi - thanks for trying to help. I don't have problem with the solution. as mentioned above, i would know what to do. The problem is, i want to simulate this so id know my solution is working. so i want to force my IE to timeout but i don't know how. I'm using Zend by the way so if a solution to zend is provided that'll be better if not plain PHP is fine.